# Interview Question - Data structure performing CRUD operation in O(1) time and maintaining insertion order

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

Recently I have attended an interview as backend developer, and I've been asked one the following question:

> Design a data structure that can perform ***insert***, ***update***, ***remove***, and
> ***contains*** operation in **O(1)** time complexity.
>
> It should allay printing all the elements in **O(n)** time maintaining the **insertion order** of
> elements.

Can someone please explain which data structure we can use and how that data structure allows to achieve the required **O(1)** time complexity?

Comment: printAll should be O(n) and other operation in O(1)

Comment: LinkedHashMap will address this usecase. Refer https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2015/12/how-linkedhashmap-works-in-java.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your interviewer was talking about a composite data structure which combines a [*Linked list*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) and a [*Hash table*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

And JDK offers and implementation of such data structure in the form of [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), which is basically a combination of a `HashMap` and a `LinkedList`. It's methods almost as fast as `HashMap`'s ones.

`LinkedHashMap` capable to perform these operations in amortized **O(1)** time (*only if the Key has a proper hash-function, the worst case would be O(n)*):

- insertion via `put(key, value)`;
- `containsKey(key)` check;
- updating the value of via `replace(key, value)` and `replace(key, oldValue, newValue)`;
- retrieve the values with `get(key)`;

And owing to a `LinkedList` maintained under the hood is, `LinkedHashMap` can can track the insertion order of entries (updating the value of an existing entry has no impact on the order).

Here's a quote from the documentation:

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order).